# Probability can you provide answers for the following please

Tags: probability, statistics

1)A distributed system contains 4 computers. What is the probability of its failure in one year, if
probability of failure of the computers in this period are 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7?

Is it correct
Answer : 0.1 * 0.3 * 0.5 * 0.7 = 0.0105

2. The distributed system consists of 3 computers. What is the expected value of failure-free (that
   is up to a break-down) system operation during a year when the probability of one computer
   failure in this period is 0.5?
   Given,

is the following correct

Given,

Number of systems, n = 3

Probability of one computer failing in 1 year = 0.5

Probability of one computer not failing in 1 year = 1 - 0.5 = 0.5

Expected value = n*p = 3*0.5 = 1.5

ANSWER :-  1.5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Annie Praveen: Welcome to MSE ! Since you are new to this forum, you should know that while H.W. questions *can* be posted here for help, you are required to first show the efforts you have made and where you are stuck. Please edit it in. Also, you can ignore the comment of the Bot, after all it's only a Bot !

Comment: Thank you i have added my solution... I never knew ... can someone help me say if i did right?

Comment: I understand from a distributed system to mean that all the computers need to fail independntly for the system to fail. Then answer to $(1)$ is correct. Re $(2)$, are you *sure* the question asks the *expected value* ? Expected value of failure-free **period** or of number of computers running ? Please check and reproduce the **exact** wording of the question.